# how to check if a particular function exists in a class & call such dynaically

Tags: php

please can anybody help me with this? I want to dynamically call a class function! First, i check to see if the function exist in the specified class

```
$settings = New Settings();
$str = 'display';
if (method_exists($settings, $str){
// Here's what i want to do:
// $settings->$str();
```

please can someone help with suggestion or a lead forward???

Comment: What's wrong with calling $settings->$str();?

Comment: actually, i discovered nothing's wrong with $settings->$str()! I jst thought of it without actually trying it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can call a dynamic method name:

```php
echo $settings->{$str}(); // or $settings->$str();
```

Example: http://codepad.org/489KQQbk

Answer (score 0):

thanks all. I discovered:

```
$settings->$str();
```

worked. i only thought it out without actually trying it beforehand. (Maybe, that's partly because i came from a background in a strongly typed language where some things don't work)